# Extracting data from a table in kdb

Tags: kdb

Kdb question:
They're multiple rows in a table and I want to check if all the rows if the column meets a condition.
So the column `StartDay = ***`
How can I check each single row for that column?

```
Select from t where StartDay = '$"***"
```

Just gives me type errors.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Please be careful with your grammar and punctuation marks. You are very hard to read without those !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column `StartDay` is of date type like in the following example

```
q)show t:([]StartDay:.z.d+til 3;number:til 3;sym:`abc`def`ghi)
StartDay   number sym
---------------------
2021.02.19 0      abc
2021.02.20 1      def
2021.02.21 2      ghi
```

Then the following query will work

```
q)select from t where StartDay=2021.02.19
StartDay   number sym
---------------------
2021.02.19 0      abc
```

The example you have given seems like you are trying to query a column of symbol type. Here are two examples of that

```
q)select from t where sym=`$"ghi"
StartDay   number sym
---------------------
2021.02.21 2      ghi

q)select from t where sym=`ghi
StartDay   number sym
---------------------
2021.02.21 2      ghi
```

Perhaps the following guide on [where in q-sql](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/qsql/#where-phrase) will help.

Comment: Thanks Thomas got it working in the end. I had been querying a list of strings, ended up casting the columns and I was able to query using; q) select from t where not StartDay ='$"***"